# How do I add the contents of a .htm file to a string?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to add the default signature to the end of an email that is being sent from a Userform in Excel. However, due to the body being HTML (for reason I cannot change) the signature it not displaying.

I have the following code that is the location of the default.htm signature:

```
strSig = Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\Default.htm"
```

What I now need to do (and am having issues with) is add the contents of this default.htm file to the end of the body of the email. However, doing

```
.HTMLBody =  "some text <br>" & strSig
```

it just adds the location path in text form to the email.

How do I get it to insert the contents of the HTML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it

```
Dim FSO As Object : Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim strSig As String
Dim pthSig As String

pthSig = Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\Default.htm"
strSig = FSO.OpenTextFile(pthSig).ReadAll ' signature content

.HTMLBody =  "some text <br>" & strSig
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the file content from the path first.

```
Dim ff As Integer, sigTxt as String

ff = FreeFile
Open strSig For Input As #ff
    sigTxt = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
Close

.HTMLBody = sigTxt
```